# I want a get all the folders and subfolders from adls location

Tags: python, directory, databricks, storage, subdirectory

Getting list of all folders and subfolders from adls location.
It should not incluse file name.
some folder might have dept 4 or 5 or anything.

for eg. root/abcd/fgsg/hhejs/temp.txt

output
root/abcd/fgsg/hhwjs/

I want to use databricks python to execute this

I tried https://gist.github.com/mdrakiburrahman/dade03380b8907c85341ece18c795e4e

But it gives file name also